# Why use image1d_buffer_t? Does it support normal samplers?

Tags: opencl

I am trying to understand the `image1d_buffer_t` type in [OpenCL](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/otherDataTypes.html). From what I can tell, it is an 1D image made from a `Buffer`. The advantage over an image not made from a buffer it that the buffer image can usually be much larger (it does depend on the hardware, but the min size [per this page](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clGetDeviceInfo.html) is larger). Am I correct that you cannot use the linear interpolation of a sampler however? I am looking [here](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/read_imagef1d.html).

So why even use the image rather than just a buffer?

Comment: A 1D image is esentially a buffer (as any-D image). The difference is the sampling capabilities buffer=no, image=yes. The sampling capabilities of a 1D image is the same as 2D image. Regarding the size, I think you will not be able to use more space for an image than for a buffer. It wouldn't have sense.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct that you can only use the sampler-less read functions with the `image1d_buffer_t` type, and therefore cannot make use of linear interpolation or the edge-handling features.

It's a minor convenience, but when using the image read/write functions you have the ability to change the data-type used to store the pixel values without having to change your kernel code. Similarly, you have the (sampler-less) `read_imagef` function, which will normalise the pixel value for you (and the corresponding `write_imagef` function).

Comment: Are there any performance advantages to using the image buffer as opposed to a regular buffer? Is caching any smarter?

Comment: @AlexRothberg It's possible that `image1d_buffer_t` loads will use the texture cache, although given that sampler functionality is limited I'm not sure that would be the case. Without actually trying this I couldn't know for sure, but my guess would be that there wouldn't be any performance difference.

Comment: I recently faced the same problem and assessed the performance between normal and image buffers on an AMD R9 290 GPU. It turns out that at least on my hardware and my test settings there are differences (image buffers tend to be faster). So, I guess caching is indeed smarter. Results can be checked out in a corresponding [blog article](https://milania.de/blog/Buffer_vs._image_performance_for_applying_filters_to_an_image_pyramid_in_OpenCL#sec:StorageTypes_Benchmark).